# Golang sha3 is the same as kmac implementation?

Tags: go, hash, sha

I need to use the KECCAK Message Authentication Code (KMAC) algorithm in golang. KMAC is keyed hash function based on KECCAK. I don't found an implemented KMAC version in golang. I found sha3 and I test it using the following source code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/sha3"
)

func main() {
    key := IntToByteArray(int64(124))
    h := sha3.New224()
    h.Write(key)
    h.Write([]byte("foo"))
    sum := h.Sum(nil)
    fmt.Printf("hash = %x\n", sum)
}
```

Is the presented code can be considered as a correct implementation of kmac ?

Comment: No, this is not correct because it completely ignores the output length and doesn't use cShake. KMAC is specified [here](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-185.pdf), but I urge you to not try to implement it yourself (as with all crypto). [Hashicorp's Vault has an implementation.](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/blob/484a6febabe7/sdk/helper/kmac/kmac.go)